# Bash script - loop through loaded vars from a config file excluding wildcards

Tags: bash, config

I have a bash script that loads a config via `. $1`. Later in the script I would like to loop through these but exclude any starting with an underscore.

config file looks like

```
#---Comment---
myVar1="aa"
myVar2="bb"
_myVar3="cc"
... etc
```

Is this possible? what would the for loop look like. Any pointers to other threads would be appreciated as I could not find a close match.

thanks Art

Comment: A couple of questions: 1) Are you using `bash` or `ash`? 2) Do you want to loop over *all* shell variables, or just those that were defined in the config file?

Comment: @chepner just loop over the variables in the config file, but only the ones without a underscore. thx Art

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way for `bash` to know if a particular variable was defined "locally" or in a sourced file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the variables in the file with something like

```
while read v; do
    case $v in
        '#'* | _*) continue;;
        *) n=${v%%=*}
            echo "Value of $n is ${!n}" ;;
    esac
done <"$1"
```

The `${!var}` indirect reference is a Bash v2 extension.

Comment: outstanding, thx for the quick answer. does what I need simply.

Comment: Wouldn't this need another temporary file or subshell to get the variables parsed? Quite expensive compared to just using `printf`.

Comment: No temp file or subshell here; not sure what you mean?

Comment: Yes my comment no longer applies to your new edit. On second note, using `IFS== read VAR VALUE` would be easier than using `${v%%=*}` and also have a possible one-liner than the one I had. `${!$n}` could also give an unexpected error if `$n` provides an invalid parameter.

Comment: @tripleee not sure if related just to AWS, but on an EC2 instance I got  bad substitution using ${!$n}, however ${!n} works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you're parsing declaration of variables in the file? Many conservative old-school scripters would disagree on this but using `eval` is easiest and fastest for that approach. Even so if you want a safer one, you'd have to separate the two tokens and use printf:

```
while IFS== read A B; do
    [[ $A != #* && $A == +([[:alpha:]_])*([[:alnum:]_]) ]] && printf -v "$A" "%s" "$B"
done < "$1"
```

Of course depending on the complexity of your config files, additional checks may be added, but I doubt more obvious unhelpful conservative approaches would be needed. Anyhow the concept of the above script would be helpful enough for a start.

Notes:

`$A != #*` checks if line doesn't start with `#`.

`+([[:alpha:]_])*([[:alnum:]_])` checks if it's a valid parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have sourced a file, there's no way to later determine if a variable was defined in the sourced file or "locally". You'll have to process the config file manually, as tripleee suggests.

If the variables in the config file share a unique prefix, however, you can use a form of parameter expansion to iterate over the matching names. Suppose, for example, the config file only defines parameters starting with "myfoo" (or, of course, "_myfoo").

```
# Simple example: show values of all shell variables
# whose name starts with "myfoo". Anything starting with _
# is implicitly skipped
for var in "${!myfoo@}"; do
    echo "$var=${!var}"
done
```